# Write input label once for both form helper and form validation class

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, continuous-integration, validation

Is there a way to create html form labels using the values I've already put in form_validation rules? Example...

**controller:**

```
$config = array('somerule' => 
                      array('label' => 'Nick name',
                            'field' => 'nickname'
                            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[255]')
               )
```

**view:**

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
<?php echo form_label('Nick name', 'nickname'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('nickname', set_value('nickname', $data['nickname'], array('id'=>'nickname')); ?>
</form>
```

I need to write "Nick name" in both validation rule and inside the html view. Is there a magic function like `$this->form_validation->get_label('nickname')` that would give me the right label / language instead of writing once again "Nick name" in the view?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [CI Language class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)?

Make your own language file e.g. `form_lang.php` and place it in `application/language/english` folder (assuming your default language is `english` which is defined in config).

write your language phrase in this pattern:

```
$lang['index']="value";
```

Load language file once in your controller

```
$this->lang->load('form');
```

And that's it!
you can use `$this->lang->line('index')` in your controller (your validation config array) and loaded views, too.

Use `$this->lang->line('index')` in your view which has been loaded by your controller.